# Searching for an element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, vaadin7

I need to wrap ChosenJS jq plugin into Vaadin component. I suppose it makes some jq queries at the moment of initialization.

So my `<select>` element should be attached to DOM at the moment when I call `$().chosen()`.

Vaadin components are being bound dynamically: when you make some dynamic markup you have only a detached Widget which can provide an Element and these elements are being nested into DOM after that. So I try to make a deferred function call with GWT Timer (I think it uses `setTimeout` or `setInterval` inside) thinking that it will work when the widget element will present in DOM.

Here is a piece of code http://pastebin.com/E3YdLC48 . But it does not work indeed.

There are couple of tests in the snippet.

**Line 15-19** shows that the widget is still detached.

**Line 34** launches in 30 seconds test when the element supposed to be in the DOM. I can really see it in browser debugger. 30 seconds can be enough to make sure you can see it on the form and in debugger.

**Lines 24-28** making sure that the `<select>` element is not detached. It prints all elements from `<select>` to `<html>`.

**Line 29** works too.

It is a gwt method and it finds the element by ID.

**Lines 38-43** failing to locate my element.

**Line 42** - empty jq wrapper.

**Line 42** - null.

Please help me to understand why I cannot find my select `<element>`.

```
public ChosenImpl(VChosenUI target, final ChosenServerRpc rpc) {
    StyleInjector.injectStylesheet(ChoosenStaticApi.INSTANCE.chosen_css().getText());
    ScriptInjector.fromString(ChoosenStaticApi.INSTANCE.jquery_min_js().getText()).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromString(ChoosenStaticApi.INSTANCE.chosen_jquery_js().getText()).inject();
    this.rpc = rpc;
    select = DOM.createSelect();
    select.setAttribute("id", "artix-chosen-id-" + select.hashCode());
    select.setAttribute("multiple", "");
    select.setAttribute("data-placeholder", placeholder);
    //select.setAttribute("style", "");
    this.target = target;
    target.addStyleName("artix-chosen-target");
    target.getElement().appendChild(select);

    Element pp = select;
    while (pp != null) {
        logg(pp);
        pp = pp.getParentElement();
    }
    Timer timer = new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Element pp = select;
            while (pp != null) {
                logg(pp);
                pp = pp.getParentElement();
            }
            logg(DOM.getElementById("artix-chosen-id-" + select.hashCode()));
            findSelectInDOM("artix-chosen-id-" + select.hashCode());
        }

    };
    timer.schedule(30000);
}

public static native void findSelectInDOM(String jqselector) /*-{
 console.log("===============================================================");
 console.log(jqselector);
 console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("select"));
 console.log($("#"+jqselector));
 console.log(document.getElementById(jqselector));
 console.log("===============================================================");
 }-*/;
```

Comment: You should include any code required to understand the question directly into your question, not available only via an external reference (per StackOverflow rules).

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but instead of doing `console.log("===")` to block off your log entries, you should try using `console.group();` instead of the first `console.log("===")` and `console.groupEnd()` as the second one.

Comment: Found out, that my widgetset is being loaded inside `<iframe>`. And widgetset pulls these libraries: jq and chosen. So they are in the same iframe. Don't know if it is important.